# Laravel 8 pagination for many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have many to many relation for categories and products. In a specific category page I want to add pagination for products.

This is my code in Category model:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,
        'category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id'
    )
    ->where('is_published',1)
    ->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(5);
}
```

This is CategoryController code:

```
public function show($id) {       
    $category = Category::findorfail($id);        
    return view(category.show, compact('category'); 
}
```

This is a pagination code in category view blade:

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

This is an error I'm getting:

```
App\Models\Category::products must return a relationship instance.
```

Any solutions?

Comment: delete `->paginate(5);` from your model

Comment: @EsTeAa Ok, but where should I add this?

Comment: You need to add it on your controller

Comment: @EsTeAa How can I do that, can you explain?

Comment: Post your controller code

Comment: @EsTeAa ```public function show($id) {
      $category = Category::findorfail($id);

      return view(category.show);
}```

Comment: That should be `$category = Category::with('products')->paginate(5);`

Comment: Please edit and add the code into your question instead of post as a comment :)

Comment: @EsTeAa That's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this:

CategoryController:

```
public function show($id) {       
    $category = Category::findorfail($id);
    $category->setRelation('products', $category->products()->paginate(5));
    
    return view(category.show, compact('category'); 
}
```

View blade:

```
@foreach($category->products as $product)
    {{ $product->title }}
@endforeach

{!! $category->products->render() !!}
```

Category model:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,
        'category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id'
    )
    ->where('is_published',1)
    ->orderBy('id','ASC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty obvious, The relationship method **must return a relationship instance.** So these two are gonna work because those return an instance of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` class:

```php
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,
        'category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id'
    );
}

// Or

public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,
        'category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id'
    )
    // This update the internal query of the relationship instance to query the relationship later on.
    ->where('is_published',1)->orderBy('id','ASC');
}
```

Your code will return an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`, which is NOT gonna work:

```php
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,
        'category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id'
    )
    ->where('is_published',1)
    ->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(5);
}
```

Then in your controller, you can do something like:

```php
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
        $products = $category->products()->paginate(5);

        return view('categories.show', compact('category', '$products'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working, but displaying all products on every page

Comment: That's not a solution for me